# What word to use to describe the mathematical objects and axioms of a branch of math

Tags: logic, arithmetic

I'm trying to write a paragraph which describes the objects and rules of a branch of mathematics. But I'm stuck as to what word I should use here.

Example: (fill the blank)

Arithmetic is an example of a  mathematical ____ that is defined in terms of the objects it uses (numbers and operations) and a finite number of rules (or axioms) which are true statements about the ____.

At the moment I'm just using 'system' because I don't know what else to use but I'm not sure this is a good word or if there is a more formal term.

Comment: Does "theory" work? This is used _within mathematical logic_ to describe a mathematical model of arithmetic reasoning built within logic -- but I think it is also used with a fuzzier meaning _outside_ logic.

Comment: Well, if you fill the blanks with "theory", then the first part becomes "Arithmetic is an example of a mathematical theory" which is not really a good way to describe *arithmetic*

Comment: I wouldn't use the same word twice. Try: "Arithmetic is an example of a mathematical **subject** that is defined in terms of the objects it uses (numbers and operations) and a finite number of rules (or axioms) which are true statements about **those objects**."

Comment: The term you are looking for might be "conservative extension", but that may be a bit too specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a slightly different context, the word *Structure* would be a good fit. Learn about mathematical structures [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure).

Otherwise, *System* is a reasonably good fit. In a slightly different context, *theory* might also be appropriate, as Henning Makholm suggested.

Comment: Structure looks like the correct term, but I think it may sound too formal/odd for a layman's description, especially if the reader does not know the meaning behind the term.  I feel like I would have to define what structure is prior to using it.  I might stick with system for now...